Help filling drill holes in glossy white melamine cabinet
Today I was drilling holes for our cabinet pulls in our kitchen and measured wrong for one of them. Once my girlfriend noticed my mistake, I redrilled in the correct spot.
Unfortunately, now I have an awful drill mark just above where my pull is mounted. Do you all any ideas on how to patch it? For reference, the cabinets are made of a high gloss white melamine.

Put a picture of your GF over the the hole/mark.  Pictures of flowers or a key set holder will work also.  You want a design statement instead of a patch work.

There are self adhesive melamine "patch dots" which aren't a perfect solution but might be good enough. Or I suppose you could get a fresh sheet of matching melamine and use contact cement to laminate it over the original layer, redrilling only the holes you actually want. Not sure I consider either of those a good enough answer, though.

Repair
Having done the same to a counter top, I filled the holes to slightly below the top with spackle (likely wood filler would have been stronger, but I wanted a white substrate). When the spackle hardened, I applied white epoxy, then used a plastic squeegee (old credit card) to flatten and to blend the transition.
The repaired holes are not apparent with a brief glance, but if one looks for it, they're still visible. Also, white epoxy may yellow over the years. Perhaps if some titanium dioxide powder (titanium white) were mixed into the epoxy, it might stay white longer.
If your friend is not satisfied, sand the repair carefully, and use enamel paint, such as for painting models, to improve the match. Blend enamel colors, counting drops of each color used, on a piece of white cardboard, and let dry, to get the best match.
For example, you might make a series with 10 drops white and 1 drop gray, 10 drops white and 2 drops gray, 10 drops white and 4 drops gray... to see what the color is when dry. Use the same ratio when painting the cabinet.
Workaround
Add escutcheons (backplates) to all the cabinet pulls, such as these, large enough to cover the hole. And tell your significant other that they'll protect the cabinets from fingerprints. ;-)
All references were cited as examples only. Likely you can find better and/or less expensive items locally.
